# Opening new tabs from background script issue

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

First of all, sorry for my english, but I try my best) I have no idea whats wrong with my chrome extension. In background script I create some notifications with action by click on it. Action - open new tab with some link. When I click on the notification at first time - everything is ok, but if I click on the second notification, script open 2 different tabs with first link and with second link. The same situation with 3rd, 4th, 5th .... notification: in the next time script open +1 previous link.
There is a responsible fragment of source code:

```
var myNotificationID = null;

chrome.notifications.create(
    'name-for-notification', {
        type: 'basic',
        iconUrl: 'yes.png',
        title: "CONTENT WAS PUBLISHED",
        requireInteraction: true,
        message: "Link: " + urlchk,
        buttons: [{
            title: "GOT IT!"
        }]
    },

    function(id) {
        myNotificationID = id;
    }

);
//

chrome.notifications.onButtonClicked.addListener(function(notifId, btnIdx) {
    if (notifId === myNotificationID) {
        if (btnIdx === 0) {
            chrome.notifications.clear(notifId);
        }
    }
});

chrome.notifications.onClicked.addListener(function(notifId) {
    if (notifId === myNotificationID) {
        chrome.tabs.create({
            active: true,
            url: urlchk
        });
        chrome.notifications.clear(notifId)
    }
});
```

I feel I need to clear smth but I don't know what exactly. Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: If the posted code is *inside* some function then you attach a new onClicked listener each time in addition to the previously attached ones.

Comment: But if I put it outside, I got an error "Error in event handler for notifications.onClicked: ReferenceError: myNotificationID is not defined"

Comment: Huh, this is what programming is about: rework the function.

Comment: How?) I'm a newbie in programming and js